# For same image,skimage can show it,but opencv can't

Tags: opencv, scikit-image

As you can see,for same image,skimage can show it,but opencv hangs,

```
from skimage import io
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('../../../data/video/vtest.avi')

ret, frame = cap.read()

# skimage can show it
io.imshow(frame)
# but opencv can't
cv2.imshow("Prvs", frame)
cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF 

 [![running result][1]][1]
```

Would you tell me:
   1,why?
   2,For similar case,how to debug opencv?

Comment: Not sure about your opencv knowledge hee, but you do know you need to follow "imshow" by "waitkey" for something to show up right ? From doc : This function should be followed by waitKey function which displays the image for specified milliseconds. Otherwise, it won’t display the image. For example, waitKey(0) will display the window infinitely until any keypress (it is suitable for image display

Comment: sorry,I actually added "cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF",just forgot to paste it here

Comment: waitKey(1) would only wait for 1 ms, and you won't see the result. Replace it with waitKey(0)

Comment: didya try waitKey(0) ?

Comment: @DmitriiZ.you are right,after chagned to 0,image showing now